# XML Conditional assignment for more than one condition

Tags: xml, field, conditional-statements

I want to assign one field based on two conditions. I can do it with one condition.

```
<field name="Value"><default>GLOBAL</default>
<conditionlist pattern="[result1]">
    <condition compareValue="Database" compareFunction="equals">MSSQL</condition>
</<conditionlist>
```

but how to do 
if(result1 = Database and result2 = Microsoft) Then name=MSSQL

Comment: Some application is using XML to express conditional assignment.  You need to tell us what that application is.  XML itself has no conditional semantics.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to solve it now.

GLOBAL

    MSSQL